# Переменная не доступна nodejs

Tags: node.js, объекты, websokets

Пишу чат на `NodeJS` и `Socket.IO` и делаю вывод сообщений в json на странице `http://127.0.0.1/messages`

1. Делаю запрос на сообщения из БД Mysql и получаю :

   `id` (ID сообщения), `user_id` (ID автора сообщения), `msg` (текст сообщения)
2. После с по id автора получаю его аватар и имя и все пихаю в один object

Код:

```
   app.get('/messages', function(req, res) {
          var messages = {};
          db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM `chat` LIMIT 0, 30', function(err, rows) {
                     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                     for (var prop in rows) {
                        connection.query('SELECT user_name, user_photo FROM `users` WHERE user_id = "'+rows[prop]['user_id']+'"', function (error, result) {
                            messages[rows[prop]['id']] = {user_id: rows[prop]['user_id'], msg: rows[prop]['msg'], info: result};
                        });
                     }
                     res.send(JSON.stringify(messages));
                     connection.release();
                });
          });
});
```

Но в `object messages` нечего не записывается и мне выводит на странице `{}`

Comment: Очередной вопрос про непонимание асинхронной логики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действия, которые вы делаете в `for` - асинхронны. Как следствие, запрос отправляется **до** того, как все эти действия будут выполнены.

Решение проблемы очень простое: вам нужно **сначала** выполнить каждый из запросов в `for` и только когда все эти запросы **будут выполнены** - отдавать ответ.

---

Существует большое количество реализаций асинхронных циклов. К примеру, вы можете использовать библиотеку [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var messages = {}
async.forEachOf(rows, function(row, prop, cb) {
    connection.query('SELECT user_name, user_photo FROM `users` WHERE user_id = "'+ row['user_id']+'"', function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            // Не удалось выполнить запрос
            return cb(error);
        }

        messages[row['id']] = {
            user_id: row['user_id'],
            msg: row['msg'],
            info: result
        };

        cb();
    });
}, function(err) {
    connection.release();

    if (err) {
        // Вам нужно как-то обработать ошибку.
        return;
    }

    res.send(JSON.stringify(messages));
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! :)